# Typeset material outside the logical page

Tags: margins

I use the `geometry` package to define the physical page and the logical page sizes. For editing purposes I would like to print some material outside the logical page, i.e, outside the crop marks.

I have seen that on the texbook, where Knuth prints some words (for indexing??) outside the crop marks.

I did not find any package that can do that. The packages that print notes they put them in the margin. I would like to have a command that put the material at the same height that `\marginpar` does; and another that put the material at the top of the page.

I am using LuaLaTeX so, lua solutions are also welcome.

EDIT 1

@egreg solution work to put the notes in the right margin.
I am trying to put them in the left side with the modified version:

```
\newcommand{\extramarginpar}[1]{%
\marginpar[\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{1.2cm}\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{#1}}]{}%
}
```

but I get the error:

```
! Argument of \@makebox has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

I checked the makebox command but I can find where is the error.

Comment: Perhaps `crop` package can be useful. It allows you to define your own crop marks, and you could hack that to insert any material there.

Comment: You can probably just increase `\pdfpagewidth` after using geometry  which TeX doesn't really use for anything but which the pdf reader uses to clip the content.

Comment: Shouldn't the title be 'outside the logical page'? Outside the physical page is when my inkjet printer spews ink on the wall. ;-)

Comment: @AlanMunn: You are right. I will edit it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
  layout=a5paper,
  layouthoffset=3.075cm,
  layoutvoffset=4.35cm,
  showcrop,
}

\newcommand{\extramarginpar}[1]{%
  \marginpar{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{2.2cm}\parbox[t]{3cm}{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}
This has a comment\extramarginpar{outside}
\end{document}
```

[image]